# Filer for HP EVA 4400 Array

Tags: storage, hp, emc

We are planning moving some of our infrastructure to the dataceneter.Most of our hardware is EMC/Dell and datacenter uses HP.
 One of the components we use is EMC Celerra NS20 Filer connected to the EMC CX3-10 storage array.This is the primary device for users to access CIFS shares.
 Now I am trying to move some infrastructure to the datacenter, some files would need to be served there as well.
The idea was to buy standalone Celerra (without any integrated storage) and connect it to the EVA 4400 that is already available in the datacenter.this would also let us use Celerra replicator for keeping two Celerras in sync if needed.
   I have spoken to EMC support if it is possible to use EVA4
400 as storage for Celerra and their answer was "we don't support 3rd party storage", which is perfectly understandable.

Now I have two options :

1. Buying Celerra with integrated storage .This will cost a lot than initially planned but solves the problem completely.
2. Buy other filer that can be supported using EVA 4400  .Keeping Celerra and non EMC filer would be a next challenge in this case.

I have checked HP site and could not find any device that is similar to Celerra.
What are the other filers that would work with HP storage? Do I have any other options to replicate rather than using  EMC software?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

HP storage kit isn't generally SUPPORTED with anyone else's kit but it depends what you want to do with it. You could make it present it's LUNs to your Calerra which could then sub-share it onwards to your clients but it is an FC-only device in itself, any other protocols it 'supports' are actually handled by ancillary devices packaged around it.

What are you actually trying to achieve? If you could add a comment explaining to this response I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

 We are trying to split filestorage served by celerra so itis available at two sites.Ideally this means buying second Celerra for the second site( so secondary site can replicate to primary for backup/dr).I have hoped that I could hook it up to the EVA4400  that is already available on the secondary site.
 Other option is to buy celerra with integrated storage ( pricey), or somethin else taht can replicate to celerra - like StorCenter ix4-200r ( not really a enterprise box)